# using python-poetry to publish to test.pypi.org

Tags: python, pypi, python-poetry

I have been investigating the use of Poetry to publish Python projects. I wanted to test the publishing process using a trivial project similar to the [Python Packaging Authority tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/).  Since this is a trivial project, I want to publish it to the test instance of pypi rather than the real instance.  Test.pypi requires a token to publish, but I can't figure out how to make Poetry use my test pypi token.  All the documentation I can find uses HTTP basic authentication for test-pypi which no longer works.

I added the repository using this command:

```
poetry config.repositories.test-pypi https://test.pypi.org
```

I have tried creating tokens using both the following commands:

```
poetry config pypi-token.test-pypi my-token
```

```
poetry config test-pypi-token.test-pypi my-token
```

I don't find a good explanation of the syntax for adding tokens in the poetry documentation, so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I've successfully used tokens and `poetry` to upload to PyPI and TestPyPI. I believe you just need to change the TestPyPI URL you are configuring by appending `/legacy/`:

```bash
poetry config repositories.test-pypi https://test.pypi.org/legacy/
```

You can then create your token as you were doing previously:

```bash
poetry config pypi-token.test-pypi <your-token>
```

https://test.pypi.org/legacy/ is the API endpoint for uploading packages. It's a bit hidden in the documentation but it is mentioned [here](https://packaging.python.org/guides/migrating-to-pypi-org/#using-testpypi) that that is the URL you should use. Also note that the name succeeding the period in `repositories.` and `pypi-token.` is what needs to match which is why we have specified: `repositories.test-pypi` and `pypi-token.test-pypi`

Answer (score 24):

### One time setup ( per host / environment)

#### PYPI test

- add repository to poetry config
  `poetry config repositories.test-pypi https://test.pypi.org/legacy/`
- get token from https://test.pypi.org/manage/account/token/
- store token using `poetry config pypi-token.test-pypi  pypi-YYYYYYYY`

*Note:* 'test-pypi' is the name of the 'repository' aka 'index' to publish to.

#### PYPI Production

- get token from https://pypi.org/manage/account/token/
- store token using `poetry config pypi-token.pypi pypi-XXXXXXXX`

### Each time you need to publish

#### Bump version

- `poetry version prerelease` or
- `poetry version patch`

#### Poetry Publish

To [TestPyPi](https://test.pypi.org/)

- `poetry publish -r test-pypi`

To [PyPi](https://pypi.org/)

- `poetry publish`