# Publish package to PyPI with poetry using API token

Tags: gitlab-ci, pypi, python-poetry

I have a Gitlab CI pipeline that publishes a package to PyPI. I used the username+password authentication, which is no longer supported, so that the pipeline now fails with 403 Unauthorized.

The following are the pipeline definition (`PYPI_USERNAME` and `PYPI_PASSWORD` are CI env variables) and output:

```
publish:package:
  stage: publish
  image: python:3.10.9-slim
  script:
    - apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y curl
    - curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 - --version 1.5.1
    - export PATH="/root/.local/bin:$PATH"
    - poetry build
    - poetry publish --username ${PYPI_USERNAME} --password ${PYPI_PASSWORD}
  only:
    - tags
```

[image]

Following the [link](https://pypi.org/help/#apitoken) in the pipeline output, I created a new API token (scoped to the project) in my account settings and then I accordingly updated the values of `PYPI_USERNAME` to `__token__` and `PYPI_PASSWORD` to the token value (with the `pypi-` prefix).

But the pipeline keeps failing with the same error. Any idea why?

Comment: I think it's not `--username`/`--password`, it's `pypi-token.pypi` in config or `POETRY_PYPI_TOKEN_PYPI` env var; see [the docs](https://python-poetry.org/docs/configuration/#pypi-tokenname). See examples at https://stackoverflow.com/a/68901875/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython-poetry%5D+publish+token

Comment: thank you, the `POETRY_PYPI_TOKEN_PYPI` worked. I was misleaded by the PyPI documentation on the API tokens. If you want to post an answer, I'll accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's not `--username`/`--password`, it's `pypi-token.pypi` in config or `POETRY_PYPI_TOKEN_PYPI` environment variable; see [the docs](https://python-poetry.org/docs/configuration/#pypi-tokenname).

```bash
poetry config repositories.pypi https://pypi.org/legacy/
poetry config pypi-token.pypi <your-token>
```

or

```bash
export POETRY_PYPI_TOKEN_PYPI=<token>
```